Maui .Net 8 ContentPage InitializeComponenet()
In .NET MAUI When creating a new ContentPage, the build reports

InitializeComponent does not exist in this context


This is clearly a bug in MAUI and or Visual Studio 2022.
Has anyone found a solution or work around for this?
I have tried setting the Build Action to Page as suggested elsewhere but this does not help.  The option "MauiXaml" is not available for some reason.
From what I can see the namespace is correct also.

Make sure there is no other ContentPage with the same Name, and check the code-behind of that must inherit from ... : ContentPage, in many cases it requires a restart only for VS

Please try to delete the bin and obj folders, then restart VS  and try again.

DO NOT CHANGE BUILD ACTIONS until you know what you are doing, you won't even know what messed up your code until you delete and re add a file

I want to see "x:Class=" line, and the namespece + class name of the xaml.cs file. Also, I want you to write what stands selected for XAML and XAML.CS build actions.

@H.A.H. namespace SharedUi.View
{
public partial class NewProjectConfig : ContentPage

@H.A.H x:Class="SharedUi.View.NewProjectConfig"

@H.A.H. Build action is "Embedded Resource"

The pages in question originally all had their build actions set to "Embedded Resource" and MauiXaml was not available as an option.   Could this be the issue?  I tried changing the build action to "Page" but that does nothing to help.

it should be MauiXaml, create a new ContentPage and copy your code from that corrupted ContentPage

So... the project in which ALL the affected pages live is a "shared project" - i.e., an ".shproj" that originally lived "above" the other platform targets in the solution hierarchy.  Should I just move everything from that old shared project into a new Maui project?  Seems like that might be what I missed.

@DAConsulting The build action is incorrect. As Mustafa said, make it MauiXaml. Also, what is the build action for the NewProjectConfig.xaml.cs? What kind of shared project? Is this MAUI Library or what?

@H.A.H. I think that is the problem.  This is an old shared project - not created as a MAUI Library.  I need to create a MAUI project and manually put back all the contents of the old shproj.  Until I do that, I cannot even select or otherwise use "MauiXaml" as an option, it seems.

@DAConsulting you should have opened with this :) Good luck with your project.

Thanks.  Yes... it's a bit hard to know what info is relevant.  I'm finding this MAUI migration to be extraordinarily painful.   Thanks to all for your help.  After I manually brought the forms into the new MAUI project and did away with the old shared project, things started to work - and I've been able to pick through the compile errors one by one.

Did you encounter any errors when creating a new Maui project for migrate?
